Can't consistently debug python code using neotest-python
I have a python project that I'm debugging in neovim using neotest-python and mfussenegger/nvim-dap.
When it works, I love it.
But it doesn't always work. In about 50% of cases, I get the error message below.
I then close nvim, open it up again, and retry. That's all. No config change, no change of venv, nothing. After one or two tries, it usually works.
As it's not reproducible, I don't know where to start with my debugging.
Any help is appreciated! My config lives here.
neotest-python: /home/ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/init.lua:119: The coroutine failed with this message: 
...ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/control.lua:293: ...ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-dap/lua/dap/session.lua:1500: adapter.command must not be empty. Got: {
  command = "",
  type = "executable"
}
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/control.lua:293: in function 'with'
    ...nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/strategies/init.lua:39: in function 'run'
    ...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:130: in function '_run_spec'
    ...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:89: in function <...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:88>
stack traceback:
    ...ocal/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/init.lua:89: in function <...ocal/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/init.lua:88>
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/init.lua:119: in function 'gather'
    ...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:94: in function '_run_tree'
    ...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:65: in function <...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/runner.lua:22>
    [C]: in function 'xpcall'
    ...ocal/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/client/init.lua:84: in function 'run_tree'
    ...al/share/nvim/lazy/neotest/lua/neotest/consumers/run.lua:85: in function 'func'
    ...e/ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/tasks.lua:173: in function <...e/ruud/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-nio/lua/nio/tasks.lua:172>

